# how to mock rcall method inside abc method

Tags: junit, mockito

in this rest abc service I am calling r system api call I have mocked fileProcessingHelper and used `when(fileProcessingHelper.rCall(client, request)).thenReturn(response);` then I am calling abc service but it is failing let me know how I can test this service.

```java
@Path("/abc")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response abc(final InputStream inputStream, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws IOException {
    var queryParams = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();

    File tempDir = fileProcessingHelper.getTempDir();
    tempDir.deleteOnExit();

    String tempFile = fileProcessingHelper.getTempFile(tempDir, inputStream);
    File tmpFile = new File(tempFile);

    okhttp3.Request requestObject = fileProcessingHelper.getRequest(queryParams, tmpFile);

    okhttp3.Response response = fileProcessingHelper
        .rCall(new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).build(), requestObject);
    isErrorArr[0] = RMTGenericConstants.SUCCESS;
    JsonObject jsonObject = fileProcessingHelper.validateResponse(response, queryParams, tempFile, inputStream,
        RMTDefaultConstants.SRA, isErrorArr);

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).header("flag", isErrorArr[0]).entity(jsonObject.toString()).build();
}

public okhttp3.Response rCall(OkHttpClient client, Request requestObject) throws IOException {
    return client.newCall(requestObject).execute();
}
```

Comment: please provide your test code and error message.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in the rCall method i am calling downstream system by passing request object for junit testing downstream system is not available then how i can mock rCall method to generate a success (201) response.